# Setting Background Color of a Windows 10 UWP App Tile Badge

Tags: xaml, windows-10, uwp

I am developing a Win 10 UWP App and I am setting the badge number to indicate the number of new stories. It is all working but my tile background color is white (due to the logo color) and the badge text color is white - so you can't see it.

I cannot figure out how to set the color of the badge text to a different color or even better set the badge background color to something other than transparent.

Like this sample image I found in the MSFT docs - where the tile background is orange

thanks
Michael

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is possible. From WP8 on, it was always the assumption that the text etc. on tiles is white. That's why all accent colors you can chose from are quite dark, so you can read white text on it. Maybe you should change your tile design ;)